# Use command line to open remote word document in edit mode

Tags: sharepoint, command-line, ms-word

Is it possible to open a remote word document in edit mode?

No any components or browsers, just use winword.exe, the file is on server.

I have searched a lot and seems have to build a sharepoint service in server, put the file into sharepoint, then open it with **/h** parameter.

But the **/h** parameter always open it in read-only mode...

Comment: If the file is `\\someserver\somedirectory\somefile.docx`, you should be able to enter `"\\someserver\somedirectory\somefile.docx"` at a command line to open the file in edit mode.  (That's assuming that the computer is set up to associate the `docx` extension with `winword.exe`.  If not, I believe you can do something like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" "\\someserver\somedirectory\somefile.docx"`.)

Comment: that somedirectory should be a share folder, right? I have considered this way, but for security the share folder should set a password, can word command line include a user and password?